# Javscript Quiz: I can't seems to save user's score

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working javascript quiz. The objective is to save the user's score.

So this is what I have. At the end of the quiz (quiz.html), an alert pops up and shows the user's score (this works fine). Upon closing the alert box, a new window, complete.html, will appear (this works too).

```
var score = 0; // Default score is 0

if (questionIndex >= questions.length) {
  alert("End of quiz! You scored " + score + " points!"); // alert user that time is up
  window.open("./complete.html", "_self"); // open a new window
  } else {
    render(questionIndex);
}
```

In my complete.html, i have the following codes.

```
<div class="quizComplete">
  <h2>All done!</h2>
  <p>
    Your score is: 
      <span id="quizTotalScore">
      <!-- USER SCORE APPEARS HERE -->
      </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

However, I tried using `document.querySelector("#quizTotalScore").textContent = score;` but the score doesn't appear in SPAN #quizTotalScore. Am i missing anything? Do I need to save the score in localStorage first for it to appear on complete.html?

Comment: It's a separate window, so yes, that line should create an `Unknown Reference Error: score`; use localStorage as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use localStorage/cookies**

Before navigating to the next page, set a variable in your localStorage

```
 localStorage.setItem("score","value");
 window.open("complete.html", "_self");
```

In your second page, in the window load event.

```
  $(function() {
     if(localStorage.getItem("variable")) {

      // set the ID here
       // after setting remember to remove it, if it's not required
       localStorage.removeItem("variable");
    }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a new html page. "score" is a variable in the previous html page.
To access the variable you need to do :

```
document.querySelector("#quizTotalScore").textContent = window.opener.score;
```

window.opener -> points to the html page which opened the new html page with help of window.open()

so here your window.opener will point the variables and functions in quiz.html